# How to define array for a spherical grid in 3d?

Tags: arrays, fortran

I want to define th(theta) and p(phi) from 0 to pi and 0 to 2pi. So this shows me the error, "real array index in u".  So what is the better way to initialize theta and phi to use in the array?

```
N=51
dr=0.1
dth=pi/N
dp=2*pi/N

do i=1,N
    r(i) = (i-1)*dr         
    th(i) = (i-1)*dth
    p(i) = (i-1)*dp
enddo

do i=1,N
    do j=1,N
        do k=1,N    
            u(r(i),th(j),p(k))=0
        end do
    end do
end do
```

Comment: How do you plan to declare `u`, or even how have you declared `u`?  What do you expect the array `u` to model?  I assume you're hoping it's some sort of field discretization, but why aren't you happy with simply using `u(i,j,k)`?

Comment: you don't even need the loop you know. just `u=0`.  Of course you'll hit the same issue as soon as you try to use it. Indices must be integers.

Comment: Did you want a solid sphere or a spherical shell (r = constant)

Comment: @francescalus, I have declared u as 3d array of dimension (N,N,N). Actually it's a part of the program so I didn't write that. I am solving heat diffusion equation in 3d spherical grid here and yes you are right, now I am defining u as a function of r,th(theta) & p(phi) and u as u(i,j,k).

Comment: @jmh I want a solid sphere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must know how your mathematics works, only after that you can do programming. The simplest way is to use structured grid, which can be programmed as a simple 3D array.

```
real :: u(n_r, -n_th:n_th, n_phi)

do i = 1, n_r
  r(i) = i * dr
end do

do i = -n_th, n_th
  th(i) = i * dth
end do

do i = 1, n_p
  p(i) = i * dp
end do
```

So you have an array with integer indexes in each direction and element `u(i,j,k)` corresponds to location `[r(i), th(j), p(k)]`.

You then access the elements

```
do k = 1, n_p
    do j = -n_th, n_th
        do i = 1, n_r
            u(i,j,k) = some_function_of_r_theta_phi(r(i), th(j), p(k))
        end do
    end do
end do
```

Notice the order of the loops! Your original order is not efficient.

Comment: Yes, I want to start theta (th) and phi (p) from zero.
This is what I have figured out for the problem:-
        `do i=1,N-1
    r(i+1) = r(i)+dr  
                                th(i+1) = th(i)+dth
    p(i+1) = p(i)+dp
 enddo

       do i=1,N
  do j=1,N
   do k=1,N
    u(i,j,k)=a*exp(-(r(i)-rmean)**2)
   end do
  end do
 end do`
Can you please explain me, why my order of loop is not efficient?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. As my reputation is less, sorry my upvote will not be displayed now.

Comment: And r(1) =  th(1) = p(1)  = 0 in the first comment.

Comment: That id just a detail. You can adjust in many various ways as you wish. It does not really matter if theta is from 0 to pi or from -pi/2 to pi/2 or something different. I just showed an example.

Comment: Your loop order is inefficient because Fortran is *column major*. It is *very important* to understand this concept. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order